# Fetch join to attribute from another object using Spring Specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_data")
public class UserData {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_cars")
public class UserCar {
    ...
    private Integer userId;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserCar> userCars;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, userCars are loaded lazily (and I am not going to change it). And now I use Specifications in order to fetch UserData:

```
public Page<UserData> getUserData(final SpecificationParameters parameters) {
    return userDataRepository.findAll(createSpecification(parameters), parameters.pageable);
}

private Specification<UserData> createSpecification(final SpecificationParameters parameters) {
    final var clazz = UserData.class;
    return Specification.where(buildUser(parameters.getUserId()));
}

private Specification<UserData> buildUser(final Integer userId) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        if (Objects.nonNull(userId)) {
            final Join<UserData, User> joinParent = root.join("user");
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(joinParent.get("id"), userId);
        } else {
            return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
        }
    };
}
```

But I have no idea how to add there a fetch join clause in order to fetch user cars. I tried to add it in different place and I got either LazyInitializationException (so it didn't work) or some other exceptions...

Comment: Ummm... `joinParent.fetch("userCars")`?

Comment: ```org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list```

Comment: Did you mark `UserData.user` as lazily fetched?

Comment: Nope. Only userCars are lazily fetched due to default behaviour of OneToMany

Comment: Why is `UserData -> User` association `@ManyToOne`? Fetching associations of non-root entities is a fairly obscure use case, it might just be it's not supported. You could try using `@Fetch(JOIN)` on top of `UserData.user`, but I'm not sure it will help. Were the `UserData -> User` association `@OneToOne`, you could make it bidirectional and query using the `User` root, it would probably make more sense

Comment: It has to be ManyToOne. I just made these classes shorter, so I removed lots of stuff here, so it might look senseless. But please, don't focus on sense of this relation, but on the problem.

Comment: Could you share UserDataRepository? I believe you might be able to set  fetching strategy there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the suggestion @crizzis provided in the question comments, please, try to `join fetch` the `user` relationship as well; in the error you reported:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

Hibernate is complaining because it it unable to find the owner, `user` in this case, of the `userCars` relationship.

It is strange in a certain way because the `@ManyToOne` relationship will fetch eagerly the `user` entity and it will be projected as well while obtaining `userData` but probably Hibernate is performing the query analysis prior to the actual fetch phase. It would be great if somebody could provide some additional insight about this point.

Having said that, please, consider to set the fetch strategy explicitly to `FetchType.LAZY` in your `@ManyToOne` relationship:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_data")
public class UserData {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

Your `Specification` code can look like the following:

```java
public Page<UserData> getUserData(final SpecificationParameters parameters) {
    return userDataRepository.findAll(createSpecification(parameters), parameters.pageable);
}

private Specification<UserData> createSpecification(final SpecificationParameters parameters) {
    final var clazz = UserData.class;
    return Specification.where(buildUser(parameters.getUserId()));
}

private Specification<UserData> buildUser(final Integer userId) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        // Fetch user and associated userCars
        final Join<UserData, User> joinParent = (Join<UserData, User>)root.fetch("user");
        joinParent.fetch("userCars");

        // Apply filter, when provided
        if (Objects.nonNull(userId)) {
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(joinParent.get("id"), userId);
        } else {
            return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
        }
    };
}
```

I did not pay attention to the entity relations themself previously, but Atmas give you a good advice indeed, it will be the more performant way to handle the data in that relationship.

At least, it would be appropriate to define the relationship between `User` and `UserCars` using a `@JoinColumn` annotation instead of mapping through a non entity field in order to prevent errors or an incorrect behavior of your entities. Consider for instance:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<UserCar> userCars;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach from the prior answer, but I think the idea jcc mentioned is on point, i.e. "Hibernate is complaining because it it unable to find the owner, user in this case, of the userCars relationship."

To that end, I'm wondering if the Object-Relational engine is getting confused because you have linked directly to a userId (a primitive) instead of a User (the entity). I'm not sure if it can assume that "userId" the primitive necessarily implies a connection to the User entity.

Can you try to re-arrange the mapping so that it's not using an integer UserId in the join table and instead using the object itself, and then see if it allows the entity manager to understand your query better?

So the mapping might look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_cars")
public class UserCar {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false) // Assuming it's called user_id in this table
    private User user;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserCar> userCars;
    ...
}
```

It would also be more in line with
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many